# Passing argument to the middle of an npm script

Tags: npm

Title says it all. I want to be able to pass the argument to the middle of an npm script so that I may do the following.

```
$ npm run deploy -- <destination-path>
```

In package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "deploy": "robocopy dist <destination-path> /E /NP"
 }
```

Is this possible without using environment variables or npm's configuration variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [Passing args into run-scripts #5518](https://github.com/npm/npm/pull/5518#issuecomment-46915480) it would appear that is it not possible to pass arguments to the middle of the script.

> We are not going to support passing args into the middle of the script, sorry. If you really need this, write your test command using literally any of the command line parsers that anyone uses. (Minimist, dashdash, nopt, and commander all support this just fine.)

However, an alternative to this using the [npm configuration block has been documented here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627#issuecomment-152607809). My implementation then looks like this:

```
"name": "foo"
"config": { "destination" : "deploy" },
"scripts": { "deploy": "robocopy dist %npm_package_config_destination% /E /NP" }
```

I can then override this on the command line and on my build server with:

```
npm run deploy --foo:destination=C:\path\to\deploy\dir
```

Comment: There is a very misleading mistake in this code: `%npm_package_config_destination%` should be `$npm_package_config_destination`

Answer (score 4):

I have a different way to do that via shell.

If your npm command is:

```
"deploy": "robocopy dist ${1} /E /NP"
```

Where ${1} is the parameter you want to substitute.

Then wrap it in a function as follow:

```
"deploy": "func() { robocopy dist ${1} /E /NP";}; func"
```

then you can run a positional parameter substitution in shell as follow:

```
npm run deploy -- xyz
```

which would run

```
robocopy dist xyz /E /NP
```

And since this is a shell script, you can use default parameters as well:

```
"deploy": "func() { robocopy dist ${1:-xyz} /E /NP";}; func"
```

And you can use it as follows:

```
npm run deploy <==> robocopy dist xyz /E /NP
npm run deploy -- abc <==> robocopy dist abc /E /NP
```

Comment: How well does this run cross environment? (Eg: windows, mac)

Comment: @Tofandel not quite sure to be honest. I only tested that in linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an environment variable to set the destination path.

`PATH=/path/to/file npm run deploy -- $PATH`

or

`export PATH=/path/to/file`

`npm run deploy -- $PATH`

Comment: I will clarify my question. I am trying to avoid the need to set environment variables to control the behavior of the script. Though this may be the only way.

Comment: In what context would you be using this that environment variables aren't convenient?

Comment: I generally prefer to pass arguments in to any executable via command line rather than via environment variables. In this specific case the `npm run deploy -- <path>` is run from a Jenkins build server. I'm not sure the example you provided addresses the issue though. I want to take the argument that is passed in at the end of `npm run deploy -- <path>`, in this case `<path>` to the middle of the command run by the defined deploy script in package.json. However, it seems npm can only pass arguments to the end of a script, and not the middle.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the arg structure of "sh -c". In my example below, I have to echo-feed the npm arg into a language parser. The argument for `npm run foma <some word>` will be in place of the `$0`:

```
"sayhello": "bash -c 'echo hello $0!"
```

A cross-platform solution I use is:

```
"arg-helper": "node -e \"process.stdout.write(require('child_process').execSync(process.argv[1].replace('$', process.argv[2] || '')))\"",
"sayhello": "npm run arg-helper \"echo hello $!\"

...
>npm run sayhello world
```

Answer (score 0):

Levereging `npm_config_*` variables.

`package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "echoMyParam": "echo 'your param value is' $npm_config_foo"
  }
}
```

Run

```
npm run echoMyParam --foo=bar
```

Result

> your param value is bar

It's important to check the docs for other cases: https://docs.npmjs.com/using-npm/config